# Vuex - Как в метод dispatch передать больше 2ух параметров?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Делаю запрос из компонента

```
created: function() {
    this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_STORY_COMMENTS', this.$route.params.id )
},
```

Action выглядит так:

```
    FETCH_USERS_COMMENTS: ({ commit }, id) => {
    axios.get("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=author_" + id + ",(comment)")
        .then(response => {
            let result = response.data.hits;
            commit("APPEND_COMMENT", result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
},
```

То есть я передаю id в параметрах. Но в один момент мне понадобилось передавать не только id, но ещё три или четыре параметра из пропсов, которые повлияли бы на запрос к API 
Пытался просто прописывать через запятую или оборачивать в объект - не срабатывает, к API даже не подключается. Есть ли какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: Конечно есть. Передай объект с таким количеством полей, скаким надо. Ну вроде `this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_STORY_COMMENTS', {id: this.$route.params.id, some: 'param', more: 'someMore'} )`

Answer (score 1):

есть такое API URLSearchParams - в него передаете объект, а на выходе получаете правильно сформированную и закодированную строку для урла. developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Пример использования

```js
const baseUrl = "http://test.com";
const obj = {
id: 10,
name: 'Li',
tags: [1,2,3,4]
}
const params = new URLSearchParams(obj);
console.log(`${baseUrl}?${params.toString()}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Компонент:

```
// props = { someParams: "someData" }

created: function() {
    this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_STORY_COMMENTS', {id: this.$route.params.id, ...props } )
}
```

Action:

```
 FETCH_USERS_COMMENTS: ({ commit }, inputData) => {
    axios.get("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=author_" + inputData.id + inputData.someParams + ",(comment)")
        .then(response => {
            let result = response.data.hits;
            commit("APPEND_COMMENT", result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
},
```

Примерно так. Только следите, что бы в пропсах не было данных ключом "id", а то перезапишет.

Comment: и как будет выглядить итоговый урл?

Comment: :) Например вот так: https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=author_1someData,(comment)